# 'AppDelegate' does not have member named 'navController'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I am trying to access the `self.navController` object in my `AppDelegate.swift` file for handling receiving push notifications from Parse. I am following the Parse documentation [here (Responding to the Payload)](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-receiving-pushes). The last line of the code sample starts with `self.navController ...` but when I try to write that in my `AppDelegate.swift` file, I get the error "AppDelegate does not have member named navController." My search has shown this is supposed to be a field of my AppDelegate. Can someone explain why it's not being recognized?

Why I need navController:

I am working on a messaging app and want to open up my messages view controller when a user clicks on the notification banner that says another user sent them a message.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
let navController = application.windows[0].rootViewController as UINavigationController
```

Comment: Thanks, though this does not solve my underlying problem. I guess it's a separate issue though..

Comment: Technically your answer is incorrect since window is not an array. And I ended up using this code `self.window?.rootViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(convoVC, animated: true)`